# Atom 'autocomplete+' not working

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typescript, atom-editor

So the autocomplete+ comes with Atom when you install it and is enabled by default.

When I am writing code, nothing shows up, why?

Is there any file I need to configure before it works properly?

Comment: have you considered [this link](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript)?

Comment: Yes I already have that package installed.

Answer (score 8):

In autocomplete-plus settings page there is option "File Blacklist":
[image]

and by default there is all files back listed "*.*"
so autocomplete works only in those files which have special addon installed

I have put "*.none" and autocomplete started to work in all files for me

Comment: Finally, I have managed to enable autocompletions in `.bashrc` thanks to your answer! It took me quite a while. I had no idea why it's not working there. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For `atom-typescript` and any new typescript project in general, for things like autocomplete to work correctly, you must have a `tsconfig.json` file.  `atom-typescript` has a command to generate you a file, when you're editing a `.ts` file.

[image]

Comment: Weird, but saved half of my day :) Previous half was spent on reviewing batch of github issues with no result.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just install atom-ternjs package.

Answer (score 0):

Just install to your Atom Editor [current plugin](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript)

Comment: I already have that installed. Won't fix the problem. Whether I am writing JS or TS, it's the same. No autocomplete whatsoever.

Comment: Try to consider [this article](https://discuss.atom.io/t/go-plus-autocomplete-and-autocomplete-seems-not-working/16380/6)