# Plain text autocomplete in Atom (Github)

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, atom-editor, plaintext

I've auto-complete and auto-complete+ installed on the latest version of Atom. Unfortunately, these packages don't auto-complete or suggest words while typing plain text as open office or some sublime packages do.

For instance, if I am typing *repo* and the word *repository* already appears in the current document, I would like to have some sort of auto-completion / intellisense to show up.

I looked, in vain, for package in atom achieving that.

So, the question is, do you know any package to do that in atom or any intuitions on how to create it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the autocomplete-plus package should do exactly what you want. By default it looks in the current document, but you can enable "Include completions from all buffers" to get completions from all open buffers.

A few suggestions why it does not work:

1. Make sure "Enable built-in provider" is activated in the autocomplete-plus settings
2. The package let's you choose between two "Default Providers", Fuzzy and Symbol. Try both (for me Symbol works fine)
3. Make sure the file type you use does support autocompletion and is not blacklisted, see [this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35337256/507490)
4. Maybe the autocomplete package interferes with autocomplete-plus. Try disabling or uninstalling autocomplete