# Enable autocomplete to all the words in current document in atom text editor

Tags: xml, autocomplete, atom-editor

I work on localization to my language in .xml document.
So I need to enable autocomplete function to all the words, which already exist in document.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete-plus that comes with Atom package should do exactly this. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320708/plain-text-autocomplete-in-atom-github/35357570#35357570) to a very similar question.